# How to synchronize the drawable state of two views

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android I have an EditText and a Button next to the EditText, and whenever I press on one I would like the other to appear in the same state as well.

I tried putting android:clickable = "true" on the enclosing layout and android:duplicateParentState="true" on my EditText and Button but this only works if I touch the layout itself. If I touch my EditText or Button nothing happens. I tried setting android:clickable = "false" on the EditText & Button but the touch events still don't filter down to the parent.

How can I make my views transparent to touch events so they pass down to the parent? What I want is for the EditText and Button to work together so if I touch either one they both appear to be pressed.

Here is the XML I am currently using:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id = "@+id/EnclosingLayout"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "120dp"
    android:clickable = "true">
    <EditText
        android:id = "@+id/MyEditText"                                                      
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id = "@+id/MyButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/MyEditText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/MyEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="31.33dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This isn't 100% related to this issue, but when working on a related problem android:addStatesFromChildren="true" helped me out. Just wanted to add that if anyone comes across something similar.

Comment: Thanks. Spended a lot of time to find this solution. Your comment was very useful for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `android:focusable="true"` in your RelativeLayout instead of clickable. Im not sure what you mean by "How can I make my views transparent to touch events so they pass down to the parent?" When you click on the EditText you want the Buttons onClick() to get called?

Comment: What I actually wanted was if I clicked on the button, I wanted the underlying RelativeLayout to handle the event. In the end though I solved the problem another way and I created a fake button that I set as the EditText's drawableRight, and that way they both appear pressed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider trapping all input to the edit text and button and redirecting the event to a common view controller, in this case, a common method. Then update both the edit text and button in the common method (a view controller). For the edit text you will need to trap both on touch and on click by creating a handler for both events as in:

```
// EDIT TEXT ON TOUCH HANDLER
editTextPassword.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {    
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    SynchViews();  // view controller
                    break;
            }           
            return true;
        }
    });

// EDIT TEXT ON Click HANDLER (No touch screen)
editTextPassword.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                        SynchViews();   // view controller
        }
    });
```

Comment: I ended up solving the problem a different way -- I drew a fake button using the EditText's drawableRight property and I manipulated the bounds in the code to ensure it was the proper size.