# Which listener to use to implement selection of multiple views by sliding the finger over them?

Tags: android, hover, slide, android-view, android-event

I am confused about what I should use to listen for the event of sliding the finger across views and selecting those views. Is this a hover event? Android doc says [`The hover may be generated via exploring the screen by touch or via a pointing device.`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html) Or should I rather try to pull this off using just the onTouch events?

Comment: please link to the documentation

Comment: Linked the documentation page. It isn't an anchor link. Hover is described in the EXPLORATION TYPES section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the hover event is for devices with a pointing device. Examples are the Transformer Prime which has a keyboard with a mouse. Or the Samsung Note devices, with a stylus. You can use the stylus to hover (e.g. holding the pen above the screen, without touching) buttons/textviews etc etc.

When actually touching the device with a finger, your buttons will go to the pressed, selected or focussed states... Good luck

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out. Can I have some hints on how to highlight multiple elements in one touch of finger sliding over them?

Comment: you can put your items in a ViewGroup. Also lots of similar questions e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344666/how-to-synchronize-the-drawable-state-of-two-views